# Go through an array to find a multiple of a number with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to go through the following array and find the number that isn't a multiple of eight (58 at the end). I've been trying to figure out how to do it but nothing I tried really worked.

```
var multiplesOfEight = [8,16,24,32,40,58];
```

I tried this

```
var multiplesOfEight = [8,16,24,32,40,58];
if (multiplesOfEight % 8 === 0) {
    console.log("Multiple of 8");
} else {
    console.log("Wrong number");
}
```

and it just logs "Wrong number", I was expecting it to repeat "multiple of 8" five times and then wrong number but I guess that if/else is taking the array as a whole or something? An explanation of what exactly is happening with this if/else would also be appreciated.

Comment: you should use a for loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var i=0;i<multiplesOfEight.length;i++){
if (multiplesOfEight[i] % 8 === 0) {
    console.log("Multiple of 8");
} else {
    console.log("Wrong number");
}
}
```

Comment: Jus modified it.. Typo

Comment: Consider `console.log(mutiplesOfEight[i] % 8? 'Mulitple of 8' : 'Wrong number')`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simpler with forEach statement (open console of browser to view result when running snippet):

```js
[8,16,24,32,40,58].forEach(function(i) {
  if (i % 8 === 0) console.log(i + " is multiple of 8");
  else console.log(i + " is wrong number");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a `for` loop, however you don't even need to store the array in a separate variable. With this syntax, you can integrate the array right into the `for` loop itself:

```
for (var multiple of [8,16,24,32,40,58]) { 
    if (multiple % 8 === 0) {
        console.log("Multiple of 8");
    } 
    else {
        console.log("Wrong number");
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/37ju75c6/

Answer (score 0):

```
var multiplesOfEight = [8,16,24,32,40,58];
for(var i=0;i<multiplesOfEight.length;i++){
if (multiplesOfEight[i] % 8 === 0) {
    console.log("Multiple of 8");
} else {
    console.log("Wrong number");
}
}
```

Comment: You want to compare multiplesOfEight at i

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether each element of the array modulo 8 equals 0.

An option is to use [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```
var multiplesOfEight = [8,16,24,32,40,58];

multiplesOfEight.forEach(function(num, index){
   if (num % 8 === 0) {
       console.log("The number " + num + " at index " + index + " is divisible by 8");
   } else {
       console.log("The number " + num + " at index " + index + " is a wrong number");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you iterate over the numbers? ;)

```
[8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 58].forEach(function(n) {
  if(n % 8 == 0) 
     console.log(n + " is multiple of 8");
  else
     console.log(n + " is not multiple of 8");
});
```